# Are there test vectors available for GZIP?

Tags: c++, boost, gzip

In our software, we have an interface for GZIP (RFC 1952) compression/decompression that is currently powered by boost::iostreams. Since we might need to change the underlying lib for linking reasons, I'd like to add more tests for GZIP compression and decompression, i.e. precise byte-per-byte comparison.

Are there any official or widely used GZIP test vectors?

Comment: Generic test vectors really only make sense for decompression. Different implementations are allowed to produce different compressed byte representations.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Is it only the header (time, operating system ...) that is allowed to differ or can the data differ as well (given a fixed compression level)

Comment: I believe the actual compressed data can vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you cannot test the output of a compressor with any fixed expectation.  The compressor is allowed to generate a wide range of possible results with the same input data.  The simplest example is the selection of different compression levels trading off speed vs. size.  The only thing the compressor is expected to guarantee is that when its result is decompressed, that you get the input of the compressor.

As a result, there are two kinds of tests that make sense.  The first is round-trip testing, where you test compression followed by decompression and verify that what you got out is what you put in.  @sehe's answer provides good sources for corpora that provide a variety of input data for compressors.  You should also generate your own test data that comes from your application.

The second is testing of the decompressor with various kinds of invalid input to make sure that it behaves well, i.e. that it returns an error as opposed to crashing.  For the latter you can look at [infcover.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/test/infcover.c), which includes deflate test sequences with various kinds of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Three well-known data sets are used by researchers in the universal lossless data compression field. The first one, the Calgary corpus, was introduced in 1989 by Bell et al.. The files in the corpus were chosen to cover up the typical types of data used in computer processing. This corpus is rather old, and it contains some types of data which went out of use, but the corpus is still a good benchmark used by many authors. The corpora proposed later, the Canterbury corpus and the large Canterbury corpus, contain files of similar sizes, less than 5 MB.

Historical corpora include

- the Canterbury Corpus http://corpus.canterbury.ac.nz/
- the Calgary corpus ftp://ftp.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/pub/projects/text.compression.corpus/

The most promising page I found was:

- the Silesia compression corpus http://sun.aei.polsl.pl/~sdeor/index.php?page=silesia

> **Credit**: *That last link provided the text I used as introduction. You can read more on the respective downsides of the "old" corpora*